# Not able to log-in ubuntu using pkcs#11 module

Tags: ubuntu

With the pkcs#11 module we are not able to log-in to ubuntu operating system.
Here for this, we have taken reference from:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1557180
https://opensc.github.io/pam_pkcs11/doc/pam_pkcs11.html#idp2059072

When trying to log-in using pkcs#11 shared library, facing error like-

`ubuntu kernel: [13342.185619] lightdm[15882]: segfault at b662b48e ip b71ddd2f sp bfb35dec error 4 in libc-2.19.so[b7163000+1a8000]`

Getting this error after exit from C_Finalize (Traced using syslog)..

At log-in Screen messages getting like-
`Smartcard authentication starts, 
Smart card found, 
verifying certificate, 
Failed to authenticate`

when tried through terminal to log-in other user from default user-
able to get `authentication succeeded` at the end(before Segmentation fault in terminal) and getting error(as per syslog) -

`ubuntu kernel: [11694.542754] su[13543]: segfault at b676048e ip b7586d2f sp bfd0f0bc error 4 in libc-2.19.so[b750c000+1a8000]`

There is no problem with pam. Cause we have tested with other token, its working..
When we tried to debug this with gdb with backtrace option the result will be like-

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strlen_ia32 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S:51
51 ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) backtrace

`#`0 __strlen_ia32 () at ../sysdeps/i386/i686/multiarch/../../i586/strlen.S:51

`#`1 0xb7597732 in __GI_fputs_unlocked (
str=0xb678248e ,
fp=fp@entry=0x8fd4d20) at iofputs_u.c:36

`#`2 0xb7614789 in __GI___vsyslog_chk (pri=, pri@entry=85,
flag=flag@entry=1, fmt=fmt@entry=0xb76ebb7e "%s %s",
ap=ap@entry=0xbfe56b4c "\270K\375\b\030/\375\b\264\252n\267")
at ../misc/syslog.c:205

`#`3 0xb7614c27 in __syslog_chk (pri=85, flag=1, fmt=0xb76ebb7e "%s %s")
at ../misc/syslog.c:129

`#`4 0xb76e8a4c in pam_vsyslog () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0

`#`5 0xb76e8b93 in pam_syslog () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0

`#`6 0xb6884e38 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/security/pam_unix.so

`#`7 0xb68823d4 in pam_sm_authenticate ()
from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/security/pam_unix.so

`#`8 0xb76e35af in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0

`#`9 0xb76e2c7a in pam_authenticate () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0

`#`10 0x0804b3ba in ?? ()

`#`11 0x08049e66 in ?? ()

`#`12 0xb7547a83 in __libc_start_main (main=0x8049a50, argc=1, argv=0xbfe56e54,
init=0x804db50, fini=0x804dbc0, rtld_fini=0xb771a180 <_dl_fini>,
stack_end=0xbfe56e4c) at libc-start.c:287

`#`13 0x0804ab6c in ?? ()

(gdb) frame 10
`#`10 0x0804b3ba in ?? ()

(gdb) frame 12
`#`12 0xb7547a83 in __libc_start_main (main=0x8049a50, argc=1, argv=0xbfe56e54,
init=0x804db50, fini=0x804dbc0, rtld_fini=0xb771a180 <_dl_fini>,
stack_end=0xbfe56e4c) at libc-start.c:287
287 libc-start.c: No such file or directory.

(gdb) frame 12
`#`12 0xb7547a83 in __libc_start_main (main=0x8049a50, argc=1, argv=0xbfe56e54,
init=0x804db50, fini=0x804dbc0, rtld_fini=0xb771a180 <_dl_fini>,
stack_end=0xbfe56e4c) at libc-start.c:287
287 in libc-start.c
(gdb) q

Can any one suggest me the process of debugging for this kind of error. Because in this backtrace no file is related to our code(PKCS#11 library)

Note: In addition to our shared library, we are using smart card for log-in..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in trace statements..
Internally we called syslog() in trace, here bug raised because of not closing the log (i.e: closelog() is missing).
Now there is no problem with the module..